# Another simple limit problem

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

L'Hôpital tells us that the following limit is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but I'm wondering if there is a smart way of evaluating this limit without using L'Hôpital

$$ \lim_{x \to \frac{1}{4}}\frac{\log(\tan(\pi x))}{4x - 1} =?$$

Comment: There is no s in L'Hopital.

Comment: There was when he was alive.

Comment: Wolfram begs to differ - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html

Comment: A circumflex on an **o**, **e** or an **a** in a French name usually translates to the vowel, plus **s**, in the Americanized version of the name.  [ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex)

Comment: Interesting. What is the currently accepted spelling in modern French? Circumflex or os?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a derivative in disguise:

$$ \frac{\log ( \tan ( \pi x ) )}{4x-1} = \frac{1}{4} \frac{\log ( \tan ( \pi x ) ) - \log ( \tan ( \pi / 4 ) )}{x-1/4}$$

since $\tan(\pi/4) = 1$. So when you do L'Hopital's rule you're really just computing the derivative of the numerator at the point and dividing by 4.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $\displaystyle4x-1=y\implies y\to0, x=\frac{y+1}4=\tan\pi x=\tan\left(\frac\pi4+\frac{\pi y}4 \right)=\frac{1+\tan\frac{\pi y}4}{1-\tan\frac{\pi y}4}$

$$\lim_{x\to\dfrac14}\frac{\ln(\tan(\pi x))}{4x-1}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1+\tan\frac{\pi y}4\right)}y-\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1-\tan\frac{\pi y}4\right)}y$$

Use $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}h=1$

Answer (score 0):

Completing the solution of the lab, we have using infinites series
$$
\frac{1}{1 + h} = 1 - h + h^2 - \ldots \quad |h|<1 \quad \Rightarrow
$$
$$
\int\frac{1}{1 + h}dh = \ln(1 + h) + C = h - \frac{h^2}{2} + \frac{h^3}{3} - \ldots
$$
For $h = 0 \ \Rightarrow \ C = 0$. Futhermore, $\tan x = x + x^3/3 + \ldots$. Thus, 
$$
\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\ln\biggl(1 + \tan \frac{\pi y}{4}\biggr)}{y} = \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\tan\frac{\pi y}{4} - \frac{1}{2}\tan^2 \frac{\pi y}{4} + \ldots}{y} =  \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\frac{\pi y}{4} + O(y^2)\ldots}{y} = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\ln\biggl(1 - \tan \frac{\pi y}{4}\biggr)}{y} = -\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{x \to 1/4}\frac{\ln(\tan(\pi x))}{4x - 1} = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using equivalent infinitesimals, we have
$$ \lim_{x \to \frac{1}{4}}\frac{\log(\tan(\pi x))}{4x - 1} $$
Let $h=4x-1$, then
$$ \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\log\left(\tan\left(\frac\pi 4 (h+1)\right)\right)}{h} $$
$$= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\tan\left(\frac\pi 4 (h+1)\right)-1}{h} $$
$$= 2\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\tan\left(\frac\pi 4 h\right)}{h\left(1-\tan\left(\frac\pi 4 h\right)\right)}$$
$$= \frac\pi 2\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h}{h\left(1-\tan\left(\frac\pi 4 h\right)\right)}$$
$$= \frac\pi 2\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{1-\tan\left(\frac\pi 4 h\right)}$$
$$=\frac\pi 2$$